# XDocument.Validate custom validation messages

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I'm validating an XML file against a schema using XDocument.Validate and get validation messages which look something like this:

> The
>   'http://www.blablah.co.uk/schemas/cbds:DOB'
>   element is invalid - The value
>   '1999-0dsf2-21' is invalid according
>   to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:date'
>   - The string '1999-0dsf2-21' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.

This doesn't look too user friendly and I was wondering if it's possible to customize this message in any way? It'd be nice if I could provide a tokenized string like:

> The value {0} is invalid for the
>   element {1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but this might help you get to where you want to be.

I believe that method can take a [ValidationEventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventhandler.aspx). In your delegate, you can access the XML node if the exception is a [XmlSchemaValidationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationexception.aspx). If it is, you can use the [XmlSchemaValidationException.SourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationexception.sourceobject.aspx) property to retrieve the invalid xml node.